# Xamarin Cross Platform without Xamarin.Forms (Starter Edition)

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

Is there any option to do a Cross Platform application (preferably PCL) without Xamarin.Forms? I only have the Starter Edition and I don't feel like paying $25 a month on a side project of mine. I've searched all around and can't find an answer.

I appreciate any answer, if it's not an option I'll just do XCode.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin Forms is just one option to build cross-platform application with Xamarin. Follow MVVM pattern and write the ViewModels and Models in PCL library and then create bindings from the ViewModels to native views. It's as simple as that. I suspect that the application size will be an issue though with the starter edition.

If the side project is (non-commercial) open source you could apply for free business license: http://resources.xamarin.com/open-source-contributor.html

Answer (score 1):

[MvmmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) (MVVM-based) and [MonoCross](https://github.com/MonoCross/MonoCross) (MVC-based). You can use PCLs with each. You'll need to implement your UI code independently for each platform, but you'll be able to share tons of application logic and data models. These are not like Xamarin.Forms, in that they don't provide for shared UI code. Another [non-free] cross-platform UI framework is [iFactr](http://ifactr.com/), but it's not free, and it's intended more for enterprises.